# What are those full-blown abstraction layer for PDO and how to work it with Firebird?

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

As MySQL manual says:

"PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer, which means that, regardless of which database you're using, you use the same functions to issue queries and fetch data. PDO does not provide a database abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or emulate missing features. You should use a full-blown abstraction layer if you need that facility."
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

**What are those full-blown abstraction layers and how do I get them to use with PDO?**

I'm interested in use Firebird with PHP to support an old application that I made and port part of it's function to web.

The My SQL manual says that I should use `--with-pdo-firebird[=DIR]` in **what file? php.ini?**

I wonder if in my shared server HostGator account I am able to put the firebird driver and if it will work... Does anyone knows about it? Will I have to make a dedicated server to use data bases other than MySQL in PHP?

*Sorry for that many doubts!*

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you cannot use your own php installation on a shared server. This `--with-pdo-firebird` argument is an argument to the `configure` command of PHP. (when installing PHP)

A full-blown abstraction layer is a class which provides methods like `select()`, `join()`, `insert`, `delete` etc. (in this specific case). There exist some such libraries (abstraction layers for databases I mean) in the Internet, for example Mediawiki uses such one.

An example how to use such an abstraction layer would be:

```
$db->insert("table", ["field1", "field2"])->select("table2", ["field3", "field4"]);
```